# Local migration with List<String> in swift

Tags: swift, realm

With Realm 5.4.0 I'm trying to migrate:

```swift
public final class MyObject: Object {
   public let tags = List<String>()
}
```

to

```swift
public final class MyObject: Object {
   public let tagIds = List<String>()
}
```

Therefore I wanted to write a migration block like this:

```swift
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: "MyObject") { oldObject, newObject in
   let tags = [String: String]() // filled earlier
   let oldTagList = oldObject!.dynamicList("tags")
   let newTagList = newObject!.dynamicList("tagIds")

   oldTagList.forEach { tag in
      if let id = tags[tag as String] { // this does not compile (1)
         newTagList.append(id) // this does not work (2)
      }
   }
}
```

From the oldTagList I get DynamicObjects which cannot be casted to strings (1). I was able to solve this problem by a very ugly workaround:

```swift
let oldTagList = unsafeBitCast(oldObject!["tags"] as! List<DynamicObject>, to: List<String>.self)
```

What I was not able to solve is to add the `id` string to newObjects `tagIds` list (2).

I tried to cast the list the same way than oldObjects `tags` list but that throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

How can I migrate / convert the content of a `List<String>` into another `List<String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective in the question is to create a new tag `List` for the updated objects with different tags based on a dictionary lookup. Let me set this up for clarity

Here's the existing object with a tag `List` (of strings)

```
object_0
   tags = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and the new object will look like this

```
object_0
   tagIds = ["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c"]
```

the lookup is done through an existing dictionary that would look like this

```
tags ["a": "tag_a",
      "b": "tag_b",
      "c": "tag_c"]
```

So a maps to tag_a, b maps to tag_b etc

Here's the migration block to do that

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: MyObject.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
    let oldTags = oldItem!["tags"] as! List<MigrationObject>
    let tagCount = oldTags.count
    
    let updatedList = List<String>()
    
    for index in 0..<tagCount {
        let oldTag = oldTags[index]
        let val = "\(oldTag)" //make the NSTaggedPointerString a String
        //let val = oldTag.description this may work as well
        
        if let updatedTag = self.tags[val] {
            updatedList.append(updatedTag)
        }
    }
    
    newItem!["tagIds"] = updatedList
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. My app is already in the field so i have to deal with List<String>. In the example you provided you missed the step where i converted the content of the list (tag -> tagId). It is not only renaming the list.

Comment: @liefersfl You are not converting the content of the List. The List property in the original object is defined as `let tags = List<String>()` and the new object it's the same content `let tagIds = List<String>()` just a different name. We're not actually renaming the property, we're adding a new property and migrating the data the old property contains to the new property - which is what my code does.

Comment: If you have a look at my migration code, i loop through all entries of oldObject.tags, look them up in a dictionary and put the corresponding values in the dictionary into newObject.tagIds.

Comment: @liefersfl Understood. That process was not outlined in the question and we don't know what `tags` is or when that comes into play. Can you update the question? Also, what does `tags[tag]` actually return - can you include that object? I have a solution and will update my answer but want to make sure it matches what's you're doing - the statement *this does not compile* is concerning as there is no reason (shown) it would not compile.

Comment: I updated my question by adding the definition of `tags` and added the cast to `String` which causes the compiler error.

Comment: @liefersfl Ok. I got you - check out the updated answer.

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly! Thank you! Btw. i used `oldTag.description`.