# Realm Swift Error: Embedded objects cannot be created directly

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration, realm-embedded-object

I am trying to migrate an object with a property of type `List<String>` to type `List<ChildObject>` where `ChildObject` is a custom `EmbeddedObject`.

### Example

Here's what I mean:

```swift
import RealmSwift

final class ParentObject: Object {
    // Previously, this property was of type `List<String>`.
    @Persisted public var children: List<ChildObject>
}

final class ChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    @Persisted var name = ""
}
```

I'm using this code to perform the migration, which is producing the error:

> Embedded objects cannot be created directly

```swift
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1) { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
        migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ParentObject.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
            let childrenStrings = oldObject!["children"] as! List<DynamicObject>
            let childrenObjects = newObject!["children"] as! List<MigrationObject>

            // I'm trying to retain the previous values for `children` (of type `String`) 
            // where each value is used as the `name` property of a new `ChildObject`.
            for string in childrenStrings {
                childrenObjects.append(
                    // This line produces the error :(
                    migration.create(ChildObject.className(), value: [string])
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

### Question

How do I perform the migration while retaining the previous values?

Comment: Since you're just adding a new object with the value from the old object, why not just iterate over the childrenStrings like you are and within that loop create the new object `let c = ChildObject()` assign the value `c.name = string` and add it to the object?

Comment: Hi, Jay. I run into a couple type mismatch issues with this. At `c.name = string`, I get `Cannot assign value of type 'DynamicObject'` (to `String`). I can work around this with `String(describing:)` as Rob noted. However, I get a bit lost where you say “add it to the object” due to the type mismatch between `newObject!["children”]` and `ChildObject` (`c`).

Comment: Actually, this seems to work well: `newObject!["children"] = childrenStrings.map { /* create new child object and assign name */ } as [ChildObject]`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Cool. I thought that may work. That error you mentioned is because of the string cast to `List<DynamicObject>`. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887626/local-migration-with-liststring-in-swift) for a quickie way to take the items from a List and convert them to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create a `Dictionary` with all of the property name/value pairs of each child object and create the new `List` in its entirety with an Array of those pairs.

But first you need to extract the `String` values from the old `List` of `children`. The reason this is necessary is because Realm does not represent the element of `List<String>` as an actual `String` (which is a struct). We can extract the actual value from the `description` field:

```
childrenStrings
    .map { String(describing: $0) }
```

Once you have the name you can represent the new `ChildObject` with a `Dictionary`. Note that you will have to include all property names and values in the `Dictionary`. Since we only have one, called "name", we include that:

```
childrenStrings
    .map { String(describing: $0) }
    .map { ["name": $0] }
```

Your error message said:

> Embedded objects cannot be created directly

However, you can create your new objects using an `Array` of `Dictionary` where the `Array` corresponds to the `List` and each `Dictionary` corresponds to a `ChildObject` object. Putting it all together we have:

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ParentObject.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    let childrenStrings = oldObject!["children"] as! List<DynamicObject>

    newObject?.setValue(
        Array(
            childrenStrings
                .map { String(describing: $0) }
                .map { ["name": $0] }
        ),
        forKey: "children"
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I might set the value with something like `Array(childrenStrings.map { [$0] })` to avoid mapping twice, but this is great.

Answer (score -1):

To summarize the solutions from Rob and Jay respectively:

### Option 1

This is Rob's solution with modifications.

```swift
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ParentObject.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    let childrenStrings = oldObject!["children"] as! List<DynamicObject>

    newObject!.setValue(
        Array(childrenStrings.map { [$0] }), 
        forKey: "children"
    )
}
```

### Option 2

This is a solution based on Jay's suggestions. It creates fewer arrays (or dictionaries if using named parameters) and should scale better with more complex objects.

```swift
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: ParentObject.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    let childrenStrings = oldObject!["children"] as! List<DynamicObject>

    newObject!["children"] = childrenStrings.map {
        let childObject = ChildObject()
        childObject.name = "\($0)"
        return childObject
    } as [ChildObject]
}
```