# How do I add an embedded object to a list in mongodb realm in react-native in typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, react-native, realm, one-to-many

I have created a class (see example below) for a collection in my realm database which has a property c which is a list of an embedded object yyyy that I have also defined.  When a new xxxx document is created, c is empty.  I want to be able to add new objects yyyy to the list c, but when I try to do that, I get an error stating: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Embedded objects cannot be created directly., js engine: hermes

I can't work out how to make this work! Any help very much appreciated, thanks!

```
class xxxx extends Realm.Object<xxxx> {
    _id!: BSON.ObjectId;
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: Realm.List<yyyy>;

    static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
        name: 'xxxx',
        primaryKey: '_id',
        properties: {
            _id: {type: 'objectId?', default: () => new BSON.ObjectId()},
            a: 'string?',
            b: 'string?',
            c: {
                type: 'list',
                objectType: 'yyyy',
            },
        },
    };
}
```

I am trying to add a new object yyyy, defined as:

```
export class yyyy extends Realm.Object<yyyy> {
    _id!: BSON.ObjectId;
    y?: string;
    z?: string;

    static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
        name: 'yyyy',
        embedded: true,
        properties: {
            _id: {type: 'objectId', default: () => new BSON.ObjectId()},
            y: 'string?',
            z: 'string?',
        },
    };
}
```

to a list within my parent object by trying this kind of thing:

```
    const instanceForUpdate = useQuery(xxxx).filtered('b == "something"')[0]; //this returns 1 doc
    const createYYYY = useCallback(
        ({y, z}: {y: string, z: string}) => {
            return realm.write(() => {
                instanceForUpdate.c?.push(new yyyy(realm,{y: y, z: z}));
            });
        },
...
```

but it throws the following error:

Error: Exception in HostFunction: Embedded objects cannot be created directly., js engine: hermes

Comment: I think I understand the question but the xxx and yyy and a and b etc make it a tad confusing. Also, your `yyyy` object is not defined the question. In a nutshell, embedded objects are not stored in Realm as distinct managed objects - they become part of a parent object. So if you want to add a `yyyy` object to a parent `xxxx` object's `c` property, you would (pseudo code) define `yyyy` to add - `const yToAdd = yyyy object` and then add it the `c` list `xxxx.c.add yToAdd object`

Comment: Thank you - I had tried to do something along these lines in fact, but hadn't seemed to work. I realise the question wasn't completely clear and had a couple of errors, and not showing yyyy defined in the question didn't help, so edited the question a bit so hopefully it is clearer now. Thanks again

Comment: See [Embedded Objects Cannot be created directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201892/realm-swift-error-embedded-objects-cannot-be-created-directly/69204394#69204394)